# How to delete ProgramFiles x86 and Windows folders (external hard drive)

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, external-hard-drive

I’ve upgraded an old HDD on a laptop to an SSD (the SSD has already windows on it, last update, drivers etc, so the laptop is fully operational).

I’d like to delete the ProgramFiles, ProgramFiles (x86), Windows folders on it, but I can’t, it says something like TrustedInstaller and I’m not able to do it.

I try CMD and System user change method and esos data wipper and win zip to deleted the folder but non work for me

Comment: It's not clear whether you're trying to erase these from the old HD or the new SSD. It should be really, really hard to delete them from the drive you're currently booted from - to prevent you completely destroying your install - but the other drive shouldn't care. It makes me think you're acting on the wrong drive… or booting from the wrong drive.

Comment: Easiest method is to completely wipe the partitions of the old HDD using Computer Management, Disk Management and recreate them. If you really want to only remove those folders, first change owner to your own user, from the root and let it propagate upwards, once done, give yourself full control on the root folder and let it propagate upwards, then you can remove the folders.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm pretty sure that in this case, the TrustedInstaller user on the old drive in the NTFS filesystem can be identified to be the same TrustedInstaller from the new drive, and as such, the same limitations apply on both drives.

Comment: @LPChip - you may be right. I'm not actually sure how Windows handles 'the same account' on two drives. You could do this on Mac without invoking the gods of unix perms at all; any drive that's not boot loses its immunity.

Comment: @Tetsujin on windows, this information is retained. In some cases, windows correctly identifies a drive as being foreign and all management rights  get ignored, especially if the local user is admin. But if the drive was present in the same windows install, the userguid is present in the local userdb and as such the same rights apply, which is likely the case here.

Comment: @LPChip - ah, OK. Makes sense. I used to have a little util back in the Win7 days that could delete anything on reboot by grabbing it before the OS did. Can't remember it's name, though. I also used to have TakeOwnership on right click, for the slightly less resistant. [I don't do Win half as much as I used to, forgetting it all slowly:\